# Import statement location

Tags: go

I am not able to understand why this error is coming and not able to find explanation wherever i have searched.

On running

```
package main

var a = 23

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(a)
}
```

I am getting this error

```
# command-line-arguments
./test.go:5: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

I understand that if i keep import just after package declaration it works  fine. What i am not able to understand is WHY import needs to be after package declaration and not this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Source_file_organization) defines it like that:

> Each source file consists of a package clause defining the package to which it belongs, followed by a possibly empty set of import declarations that declare packages whose contents it wishes to use, followed by a possibly empty set of declarations of functions, types, variables, and constants.
>
> `SourceFile       = PackageClause ";" { ImportDecl ";" } { TopLevelDecl ";" } .`

Which means you need to put your `import` statements before any other declaration.